# How to disable mouse acceleration on Ubuntu Studio 20.04 xfce?

Tags: 20.04, mouse, xfce

Can't find how to disable mouse acceleration on Ubuntu Studio 20.04.

Try:

```
$ xinput --list --short
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)] 
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]

$ xinput --list-props 9
Device 'KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse':
Device Enabled (176):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (178): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (314):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (315):   0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (316):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (317):   0, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (318):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (319): 2
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (320): 2
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (321):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (322):    0
libinput Accel Speed (323): 1.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (324): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (325):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (326):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (327):   1, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (328): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (329): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (299): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (300):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (301):    0, 0
Device Node (302):  "/dev/input/event4"
Device Product ID (303):    1112, 390
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (330):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (331):   1
```

Possible change acceleration speed, and it is working:

```
$ xinput --list-props 9 | grep 323
libinput Accel Speed (323): 0.100000
$ xinput --set-prop 9 323 0.5
$ xinput --list-props 9 | grep 323
libinput Accel Speed (323): 0.500000
```

Try do it, but it don't no disabled mouse acceleration:

```
$ xinput --list-props 9 | grep 326
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (326):   1, 0
$ xinput --set-prop 9 326 0, 0
$ xinput --list-props 9 | grep 326
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (326):   0, 0
```

How to disable mouse acceleration ?